# Как в Notepad++ в базе стереть строки из другого документа?

Tags: notepad++

У меня есть два текстовых документа. В одном из них вся база емейлов (правильных и неправильных), во втором лишь пару сотен штук правильных из первого. Как мне из первого документа удалить всё содержимое из второго?

Answer (score 1):

Можете записать макрос как во втором документе вы ищете по базе и удаляете найденное, потом применить этот макрос на первом документе.
Хотя проще и быстрее всего сделать не программированием, а через обычный Excel, и функцию ПОИСКПОЗ

Answer (score 1):

1. Создаёшь новый файл и копируешь в него email'ы
2. Подготавливаешь их к превращению в регулярку (добавляешь `\` перед точкой, плюсом и другими символами, которое это требуют, если такие есть)
3. Соединяешь всё в одну строку через символ `|`
4. Копируешь получившуюся строку и используешь для замены её на пустоту во втором файле (не забудь переключить поиск на регулярки)